# save multiple row items

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with a list of items and I need to be able to set the order that they will appear on the website. I have come up with this design:

http://i56.tinypic.com/2cf5t75.jpg

Now I was wondering if its possible to save all the items at the same time by clicking on the save button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical design. Just surround everything with a "form" tag, and give each textbox a different name, like: weight-1, weight-2, etc...

By the way, I suggest to rename "order" to "weight", as it is usually done in such cases, and pre-fill each text box with numbers which are not consecutive but several numbers apart (for example: 10, 20, 30). This way it is much easier to change the order of two items without having to change them all. Also, do remember to allow two rows to have the same weight (you'll order them "as they come").

Comment: what would I be declaring as an input parameter on the post controller to handle these?

Comment: That depends on your model. If you want a quick and dirty solution,  generate the "name" parameters on the view as you loop to generate the table rows, and accept a FormCollection as parameter to the controller, which will contain every item in the post, then loop through it to extract the elements.

Comment: yeah I just figured that out actually... What about a nice and clean solution?

Comment: You need to transform your model object into another model object specifically made for the view (or add the additional properties to the original model). This model object will contain everything the view needs, including the weight property. Then you will pass a collection of these to your view, and you will generate the weight box with a standard Html.textBoxFor() call.